# Page width when resizing HTML table

Tags: jquery, html, css, html-table, resize

I am writing some jQuery to resize a table column (http://jsfiddle.net/ydTCZ/4/) which is really rough, but seems to have the functionality I need.

The problem is the columns can't be expanded past the page width. For instance, if you resize a column, it will only expand until the page width is filled.

How can this be fixed? I'd like there to be no limit on the resize, and a scroll bar to appear if the table width goes beyond the page width.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try wrapping it in a div and resize the div together with the table. I've updated your fiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/ydTCZ/8/

Comment: can u guys do somthing like: double click to back the original position ?

Comment: thanks. @ric_bfa, keep checking back, I imagine I'll do that within the next day or two.

Comment: @chrislegend  yeap, sharing ideas, this is a good functionality. thanks

Comment: @OleMelhus this is a cool work....can you pls update this with option like "grid"...i need to have equal interval while dragging... thanks